# Can i create a "OnClick" in toast action from UWP?

Tags: c++, uwp, toast, wns

I need to catch in background this click, when i use OnActivated, the app open. I don't want the app to open when I click on the action

Answer (score 0):

Sure UWP  notification active type contains Background, that means you could call registered background task to process the corresponding content instead of starting the foreground app after click the toast.

UWP can set the notification active type when sending a notification:

```cs
var content = new ToastContent
{
    Launch = "...",
    ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Background
    
};
var notifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
var notification = new ToastNotification(content.GetXml());
notifier.Show(notification);
```

For detailed information about background notifications, you can refer to these documents:

- [Handling background activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast#handling-background-activation)
- [Support your app with background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks#in-process-and-out-of-process-background-tasks)

For using above `ToastContent` api please install `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` nuget package* for more detail please refer to [Send a local toast notification from C# apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=uwp#handling-background-activation)

Comment: currently i use background task to generate a toast, but when toast has a button and i click on it, my background application opens, i don't want that to happen, is there anything i can do to make it happen?

Comment: background application ? if you set `ToastActivationType.Background` it only trigger your background but not launch your app.

Comment: yesss, but when i click in notification Action (button), the app opens. I would like the application not to open, but at the same time make a logic when the user clicks on the notification action (button)